# How to add C++ files in iphone project

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, xcode

I have an iPhone project, in this I wanted to use c++ files. I created c++ file like below:

**File->New File -> C/C++ files -> C++ File**
and named it as **ClassA.cpp**

**In ClassA.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA
{
  public:
    int a, b;

    void add();

};

void ClassA::add()
{

//    printf("sdf");
}
```

**in my viewController.mm file:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ClassA.cpp"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ClassA a;
    a.add();



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I read some posts it says me to rename .m to .mm so I renamed all .m files to .mm
And added two linker flags

```
-cclib -lstdc++
```

But It gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the C++ portion into a header file and a `cpp` file, otherwise the `ClassA::add` will be defined twice.

ClassA.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA
{
  public:
    int a, b;

    void add();

};
```

ClassA.cpp:

```
#include "ClassA.h"
void ClassA::add()
{

//    printf("sdf");


}
```

Your .mm file:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
... the rest of the file ...
```

Comment: It works fine. thank you. and How the constructor would be .cpp file? and I have to initialize a and b in that constructor of ClassA.

Comment: @ShanmugarajaG The constructor declaration should be in the .h file, while the implementation should be in the cpp. To initialize `a` and `b` use initialization list: `ClassA::ClassA(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) { /*constructor code...*/ }`