# Can we add C++ files into iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can we add C++ files into ios project? if so then what all the build settings we need to do? Is apple accepts C++ code inside ios project?

Comment: @VivekSehrawat - I need to do any settings in the xcode. or simply it runs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389102/how-to-add-c-files-in-iphone-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Just add the files to the project, as long as they have a .cpp or .cxx extension they will compile fine.

If you want to use C++ objects in Objective-C code you need to compile in "Objective-C++" mode, do this by naming your implementation files .mm instead of .m, then you can use C++ objcets inside your Objective-C classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

@Cintu : You can add C++ files in X-Code like this.

Since Objective-C is a extension/Super-set of C.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use c++ files inside ios project. And, Yes Apple accepts your app, unless it uses private frameworks.